# Initialize a structure pointer to NULL, then try to change its members

Tags: c, pointers, struct, undefined-behavior

If you initialize a structure pointer to NULL, and try to change its members, is that what you call undefined behaviour(UB)?

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct aStructure {
    int testInt;
}aStructure;


int main(void) {

    aStructure * a=NULL;
    a->testInt = 123;
    printf("%d", a->testInt);

}
```

This happens when I run it:

- I get no warnings or error messages.
- It takes some seconds for it to stop.
- It prints nothing.

I am wondering a little what goes on "under the hood" here? When I initialize a structure pointer without having initialized the structure, does C then "set something aside" with the correct members? Because it seems that I can initialize the members without having the structure intialized, only the pointer?

Comment: Yes, dereferencing a null pointer (like `a->testInt = 123;`, where `a` is `NULL`) is undefined behavior. This means anything can happen.

Comment: "_Because it seems that I can initialize the members..._" No. This code (unsuccessfully) attempts to write to memory location(s) it does not control. "_... some seconds_" are spent by the OS, clearing away the aberrant executable and cleaning up any residuals left behind. Suggest you explore writing _good_ code instead of asking about the consequences of writing bad code. "_Stay away from the Dark Side, Luke!_"

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you. If I have questions about what happens etc. "under the hood" etc. Should I ask them on cs.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you. I assume that is also the case when you try to deference a pointer that is not a structure pointer? For example like this?: "int main(void) {
 int* a=NULL;
 printf("%d", *a);
}"?

Comment: @user394334 yes any null-pointer dereferencing is UB.

Comment: I'm "old school"... It's hard enough to make progress expending effort toward an objective. When you drive (if you do) on a roadway, do you focus on reaching your destination alive? Or, do you wonder what would happen if you drove along the crowded footpath and through the lake at the park? Deliberately "colouring outside of the lines" is not creative, especially when you're learning a disciplined subject. "Under the hood" knowledge will be gained with experience, and that takes time and the struggle to do a difficult thing _right_. One legged lumberjacks wondered, "what would happen if..."

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you initialize a structure pointer to NULL, and try to change its members, is that what you call undefined behaviour(UB)?

Only a lot.

> This happens when I run it:…

C is not one thing. The C standard specifies a base language. Compilers vary in how they implement and extend that language. When asking about what specific thing happens in your program with undefined behavior, you need to completely specify the C implementation you used, including the compiler, its version, the switches you compiled with, and the hardware and operating system you ran the program on.

> It takes some seconds for it to stop.

This is unusual. In most C implementations, the program would either  immediately crash or immediately print something and complete execution.

> When I initialize a structure pointer without having initialized the structure, does C then "set something aside" with the correct members?

No.

> Because it seems that I can initialize the members without having the structure intialized, only the pointer?

It is not correct to draw this conclusion from the behavior you report. Taking some seconds for the program to stop and printing nothing is not an indication that the program successfully initialized any member of a structure.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering a little what goes on "under the hood" here?

Lets have a look! gcc 13.x `-O3` Linux x86_64 translates your program into the following machine code:

```
main:
    mov     DWORD PTR ds:0, 0
    ud2
```

It sets a memory location to zero and executes a fun little instruction `ud2` which basically means "halt and catch fire" or "lay down to die" if you will. It will generate an invalid op code exception and then close down the shop. Meaning that gcc was smart enough to notice that your program was nonsense and translated it to a similar nonsense program.

This is fully conforming behavior by the compiler. I didn't get any warnings either, since this undefined behavior bug is not violating any constrains or syntax rules of the language.

---

Since it is Easter: When spotting undefined behavior, older versions of gcc had an "easter egg". They used to look if one out of several old school "rogue-like" games were installed and then upon undefined behavior launched the computer game rogue/nethack etc. Also fully conforming behavior, though I guess the programmers were mildly amused.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a very good idea to look at the assembly code.

Comment: @user394334 This is just one particular compiler, with one particular version and set of compiler options, on one particular OS. If you tweak any of these parameters, something entirely different could happen.